# Duplicate hosted zones for hosted zone name with cloud formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I am struggling with the following problem.

I am creating stacks with Cloudformation (The stacks are the same) each stack has a VPC and a private hosted zone with the same route (lets say me.company.com).

The first stack is created fine, the second stack get the following error:

```
"Duplicate hosted zones for hosted zone name me.company.com.: ZAIN4N303O6JL, Z36EHAOJPLFUVJ"
```

When i try to do the same via the AWS console i don't get that problem, what exactly is the problem here and how do i solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Could be related to "If you use the HostedZoneName property and there are multiple hosted zones with the same domain name, AWS CloudFormation doesn't create the stack" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-route53.html Could you post the template?

Answer (score 10):

You never posted the template, but I'm guessing your stack wasn't creating a Hosted Zone, but was actually creating a Record Set which pointed to a Hosted Zone.  In any case, that's what I was doing when I got the exact same message.  If I'm correct, then the message is fairly clear.  Whether you can see them or not, in your second case there are two Hosted Zones with the same name: "me.company.com.".  If you paste the Zone Id into the search bar, you should be able to see the individual Hosted Zones.  You will either need to delete one of the two hosted zones before creating the Record Set, or alter your template to use the HostedZoneId parameter (which is guaranteed unique) instead of the HostedZoneName parameter when you create the Record Set.

Comment: The answer is correct. I got the same issue and I found in docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-hostedzonename) the answer: _Specify either HostedZoneName or HostedZoneId, but not both. If you have multiple hosted zones with the same domain name, you must specify the hosted zone using HostedZoneId_